# mongodb node group collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get this; 
I've found a few examples but not full examples,

What I have is a collection 'messages'. 
all messages have a user_id, and a 'reference' + other fields.

I can do a search on the user_id, BUT each conversation, may have 1 message, or 100's of messages.

I just want to grab the newest message per conversation.

```
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://url:27017/", 
    { useNewUrlParser: true }, 
    function(err, database) {

        if(!err) {
            db = database.db('schoolpoint_connections');

        }
});

db.collection('messages')
    .find({"user_id": student.student_ref })
    .toArray(function(err, records) {

        res.send(JSON.stringify(response));

});
```

Some examples show:  [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/) but I'm unsure how to use that:

```
db.collection('messages')
.find({"user_id": student.student_ref })
.aggregate('reference') .....
```

fails.

I've also found this method: but no explaination on HOW to use it:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

aggregation on 'reference', and sorted on 'date_sent' to grab the newest..

Thanks in advance.

Based on the supplied link, can some one share how I would integrate that into my scenerio;

```
    db.aggregate([
    { $sort: {"reference":-1, "date_sent": -1} },
    { 
        $group: {
            _id : "$reference",
            date_sent: {$last: "$date_sent" },
            id : {$first: "$_id"}
        }
    },
    { $project: { _id: "$id", reference: "$reference", date_sent: 1 } }
]).collection('messages')
.find({"user_id": user_id })
.toArray(function(err, records) {
```

Comment: Thanks @Neil Lunn, but That doesn't explain to me HOW to use it. That's very similar to the syntax in my last link;.
I've updated my question with  further variant.

Comment: You're "attempt" at syntax in the question is not even close to usage. Therefore the "how to use it" is follow the actual code examples given. I suggest you do that. Also "please don't post code in comments". If anything you edit your question to include the code. But since you likely did not actually have any code at all before you asked the question it would be better to [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead. And of course include any error and necessary data in order to reproduce.